# Deep Learning for 3D Point Clouds, volume detection and meshing

Tags: deep-learning, bigdata, point-clouds, volumes

I'm working on an archaeological excavation point cloud dataset with over 2.5 Billion points. This points come from a trench, a cube 10 x 10 x 3 m. Each point cloud is a layer, the gaps between are the excavated volumes. There are 444 volumes from this trench, 700 individual point clouds.

Can anyone give me some direction to any algorithms which can mesh these empty spaces? I'm already doing this semi-automatically using Open3D and other python libraries, but if we could train the program to assess all the point clouds and deduce the volumes it would save us a lot of time and hopefully get better results.

Comment: Deep learning is generally best at [supervised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning) tasks, meaning to get it to work, it's likely you'd have to do all the work yourself anyway (to train the system), not saving yourself any time :-/  What would you like to improve when it comes to your current approach?  Ps. Consider trying the [computer graphics stack exchange](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions) which may be a better fit for this question.

Comment: How are there fewer volumes than layers? I must be misunderstanding because I thought for 700 clouds there should be 699 removed volumes (convex hulls).

Comment: Pedantic: 10x10x3 is not a cube.

Comment: @bogovicj I am doing it all myself anyway for this one trench, once trained on this we can try to let it solve the other trenches.

Comment: @LegendofPedro sometimes a layer is made up of several point clouds hence the mismatch in the numbers.

Comment: @LegendofPedro cuboid!

Comment: @bogovicj it might have been had op not evolved the question by asking about deep learning.